# Pandas obtain share from DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, grouping, pandas

I need a smart and concise way to arrive from data_1 to data_3 dataframe.
Right now I m arrived easily just to dataframe 2.

```
DATA_1                        
key  SEGM1    SEGM2      VAL
A        K        X        1
B        K        X        2
C        K        X        3
D        K        Y        4
E        K        Y        5
F        J        Y        6
G        J        Z        7
H        J        Z        8
I        J        Z        9


DATA_2
SEGM1   SEGM2       VAL
    K       X         6
            Y         9
    J       Y         6
            Z        24

DATA_3
SEGM1   SEGM2        VAL
    K       X        40%
            Y        60%
    J       Y        20%
            Z        80%
```

Thanks a lot!

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
    SEGM1 SEGM2  VAL
key
A       K     X    1
B       K     X    2
C       K     X    3
D       K     Y    4
E       K     Y    5
F       J     Y    6
G       J     Z    7
H       J     Z    8
I       J     Z    9
```

Use the `DataFrame.div` function to divide two dataframes.  The first dataframe is grouped by the "inner levels" for which you want to calculate shares and then summed.  The second dataframe is grouped by the "outer level" which serves as the denominator for the share calculation. You have to pass `level=0` to the `div` function which refers to the multi-index level SEGM1.

```
In [2]: df.groupby(['SEGM1','SEGM2'])[['VAL']].sum().div(df.groupby('SEGM1').sum(),level=0)
Out[2]:
             VAL
SEGM1 SEGM2
J     Y      0.2
      Z      0.8
K     X      0.4
      Y      0.6
```

Numerator DataFrame:

```
In [1]: df.groupby(['SEGM1','SEGM2'])[['VAL']].sum()
Out[1]:
             VAL
SEGM1 SEGM2
J     Y        6
      Z       24
K     X        6
      Y        9
```

Denominator DataFrame:

```
In [2]: df.groupby('SEGM1').sum()
Out[2]:
       VAL
SEGM1
J       30
K       15
```